# Import data from Excel to database with compare value

Tags: yii2

I want to import an Excel file to database. I'm still learning how to import a file like Excel type.

I also want the value is `null` or not, e.g. if the value of date in Excel is null, then don't add the row to database.

```
public function actionImport() {
    $inputFile = 'uploads/voucher.xls';
    try {
        $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
        $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFile);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('error');
    }
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

        if ($row == 1) {
            continue;
        }

        $voucher = new voucher();
        $voucher->kode_voucher = $rowData[0][0];
        $voucher->tanggal = $rowData[0][1];
        $voucher->status = $rowData[0][2];
        $voucher->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the exact problem here? If you can save the Excel file as CSV, then you also might want to consider doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add validation rules to your Voucher Model to check for nulls. Then use

```
if($voucher->validate()) {
   $voucher->save(false);
}
```